# Trying to establish connection between mysql and web server but getting error with Help of Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, apache, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to connect two server one is database(mysql) and second one is webserver(httpd). In docker, image created with dockerfile and created two containers and running code in both of them. both are running, web server front-end code working fine when i tried to enter data, got errors. I looked out in /var/log/httpd/error_log ---> mysql connection cannot find host "data".
I want to know that how can i defined host of database in web-server ? Because of 2 Dockerfile connection issue, both IP addr in same subnet. What is the main issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The containers have to be in the same docker network and hostnames are service names (by default).

I advise you to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) which is designed to run multiple containers with links between them.

A priori, I would make something like that in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: db.dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=foo

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
```

Then, type `docker-compose up -d`. Finally, from web container, you would be able to reach the host 'db'.

If you want to work only with dockerfiles, it is also possible if my first sentence of this post is verified. By default, containers are on network `bridge`, so your containers probably are in the same network but you have to link them so that then can communicate. After you have launched `db` container, you have to run the `web` container with the following option:

```
docker run ... --link <db_container_name>:<db_host_name_in_web_container> ...
```

Thus, you would be able to reach `db` from `web`.

Comment: I appreciated but i want to perform from dockerfile. I have already performed from docker-compose and successfully executed but Is it possible same things from dockerfile individually ??